# is there any way run multiple command "os/exec" in one proccess in golang?

Tags: go

i want run multiple command in "os/exec" in one process, as you see below some command like "cd" not worked.

```
func main()  {
cmd := exec.Command("ls")
cmdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
cmd.Stdout = cmdOutput
err := cmd.Run()
fmt.Print(string(cmdOutput.Bytes()))

fmt.Println("..........  cd   .........")
cdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
cdcomand:=exec.Command("cd","model")
cdcomand.Stdout = cdOutput
err = cdcomand.Run()
fmt.Print(string(cdOutput.Bytes()))
fmt.Println(".......... ls .........")
lsOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
lscmd:=exec.Command("ls")
lscmd.Stdout = lsOutput

err = lscmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    os.Stderr.WriteString(err.Error())
}
fmt.Print(string(lsOutput.Bytes()))}
```

i try with another way:

    package main

```
import (
"os/exec"
"bytes"
"os"
"fmt"
)

func main()  {
cmd := exec.Command("ls")
cmdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
cmd.Stdout = cmdOutput
err := cmd.Run()
fmt.Print(string(cmdOutput.Bytes()))

fmt.Println("..........  cd and ls   .........")
cdOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
cdcomand:= exec.Command("sh", "-c", "ls && cd model")
cdcomand.Stdout = cdOutput
err = cdcomand.Run()
fmt.Print(string(cdOutput.Bytes()))
fmt.Println(".......... ls .........")
lsOutput := &bytes.Buffer{}
lscmd:=exec.Command("ls")
lscmd.Stdout = lsOutput

err = lscmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    os.Stderr.WriteString(err.Error())
}
fmt.Print(string(lsOutput.Bytes()))
}
```

it did not work too.

in cmd [document](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) writes:

> A Cmd cannot be reused after calling its Run, Output or CombinedOutput methods.

i've searched all tuts and docs for a way to do this, but i could not find any things. there was no solution in [Executing external commands in Go](https://zaiste.net/executing_external_commands_in_go/) article and [advanced command execution in Go with os](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/wOYk/advanced-command-execution-in-go-with-osexec.html)

each cmd command execute in different process so command like "cd" will not change directory .
 is there any way run multiple command "os/exec" in one proccess in golang?

Comment: A single process can create and run multiple `Cmd` objects.

Comment: i could not find any example or tuts for run or add Cmd objects to process obj, could you please make an example ?

Comment: i am familiar with cmd object,  i want all of cmd execution run in same process, i've updated my question

Comment: If all you want is to change directory, then set [Cmd.Dir](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Dir).  Otherwise, run a shell to execute multiple commands from a child process.  Note that the shell will start a process for each command.

Comment: my only purpose is not "Cd" command, because of create and start new process for each command, command like "cd" will not work, i am looking for executing all cmd in one process.

Comment: i am develoning a reverse shell or some thing like ssh, user send command like "ls" , "cd" etc. and client execute them and reply response of that command. command like cd did not work.

Comment: yes, my last choice is develop built in cd, what do you mean run shell? i search for this key word and os/exec was only way! how run shell and does it return output of each command? thanks for taking time and helping.

Comment: How to run shell: See existing answer to this question and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458625/.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

You could use `sh -c "ls && cd model"`

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "ls && cd model")
cmd.Stdout = &stdout
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err = cmd.Run()
```

On ubuntu

```
$ man sh

DASH(1)                                                              BSD General Commands Manual                                                              DASH(1)

NAME
     dash — command interpreter (shell)

           -c               Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name
                            operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the remaining argument operands.
```

---

An example using:

```
$ go version
go version go1.10.2 linux/amd64
```

---

```
// cmd/test/main.go

package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "os/exec"
        "fmt"
)


func main() {
        var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "echo 'hello' && echo 'hi'")
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr
        err := cmd.Run()
        fmt.Println(err)
        out := stdout.String() + stderr.String()
        fmt.Printf(out)
}
```

---

```
$ go run cmd/test/main.go
<nil>
hello
hi
```

Comment: thank you for answering, i test your solution and it did not work.  i tested in mac os high sierra.

Comment: @Ali.ZV what did you try, how did it not work? Your experiences differ from mine since it does work for me :)

Comment: my bad,it worked and solve my other problem but not this problem... thanks.